# Can context-free languages be automatically formalized with Metamath?

Tags: formal-languages, metamath

In [this introduction to Metamath](https://blog.ivank.net/introduction-to-metamath.html), the author suggests that the `$c` and `$v` statements can be viewed as encoding the [terminals and non-terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols) of a grammar. In [this discussion from the Metamath authors](https://us.metamath.org/downloads/grammar-ambiguity.txt), such grammars are examined for ambiguity.

Along similar lines, suppose that we choose a [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) grammar. Is it theoretically possible to generate a pile of `$c` and `$v` statements which encode the grammar? Is it possible if the full range of Metamath statements are allowed?

Comment: For what it's worth, I am expecting the answer to be "Surprisingly, no!" but don't yet have any evidence or counterexamples which lead in that direction. Also FWIW this came from the conlang community; many conlangs have CFGs and have community members interested in formalization.

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the grammar, once it's formalized in Metamath? Context-free grammars can generally be formalized as inductive types in proof assistants.

Comment: And what does "automatically" formalized mean? It looks to me like you could just delete the word "automatically".

Comment: @AndrejBauer: By "automatic" I mean something that could be codified as a program: insert grammar, get MM database. (Again, I was expecting a negative answer; I wasn't trying to ask about how to write such a program.) For me personally, I'm formalizing Lojban, and so after the grammar I will be formalizing Lojban's *logic*.

Comment: Metamath is extremely flexible. If there isn't a straightforward way to encode your grammar, then there will be a slightly less straightforward one. In general, I would recommend that you ask the question you are actually interested in, and not some abstraction of it. Do say that you'd like to formalize Lojban's grammar and logic – this way people can give you intelligent answers. As the question stands now, it is too general and ambiguous (and is collecting negative votes as a result). Please update the question. And another thing: how fixed are you to Metamath? There are other tools there.

Comment: While you're at it, tell us what sort of grammar and logic Lojban has. Is the grammar context-free? Is the language inductively generated by grammar rules? And the logic, what sort of logic is it? (Given the age of Lojban and its predecessor, I am going to guess it's some derivative of first-order logic.)

Comment: Metamath seems like the best choice; I'm not proving facts about Lojban, but [directly manipulating Lojban syntax in a MM database](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/brismu/blob/master/mm/jbobau.mm). That same repository contains notes -- if one wants to *use* Lojban logically, they merely need know that it's a standard second-order logic over relations; its models are [allegories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/allegory), generalizations of the dagger-category of sets and relations.

Comment: Just like was done for  Douglas Hofstadter's MUI system, you should be able to encode all rules of Lojban into a Metamath file, and then write verifiable proofs that sentences are actual derivable Lojban sentences. I don't know of any tool which would, say, take a BNF for Lojban and output a valid Metamath file, though, so you'd have to write that manually.

In a second step, you might also add e.g. first order logic axioms in Lojban and write proofs for logic statements in Lojban, which proof can be verified by Metamath.

Comment: It looks like you're off a good start with your [Lojban database](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/brismu/blob/master/mm/jbobau.mm). If you're stuck expanding it or need any help proving some statement, you can ask specific questions in this SE or in the Metamath mailing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are no apparent obstacles. The two nuances are typecodes and ambiguous constructions, as detailed in the second link in the question.

That said, it probably isn't a good idea to directly translate a context-free grammar to Metamath rules. In practice, grammars often encode precedence rules, unroll recursion into parser-friendly forms, make choices to avoid ambiguity, and include extraneous rules for features like comments. Instead, it may be useful to craft a simplified grammar specifically for use with Metamath.

Also, while the context-free grammar might be unambiguous for left-to-right parsing, it might be ambiguous for unification. As a result, you may need to produce several `$p` lemmas which serve as hints to Metamath about which sorts of syntax are allowed. This is important for producing quick proofs with `improve all`.